# what is the error in this programme?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

i need to find out as to why i land up in this error always.
Image has been attahced for the same.

pyautogui is installed.
Please help me in this case.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah5d5.png)

Comment: show your code as text

Comment: change the name of the pyautogui.py file, it is a bad practice to call the files with names that match the libraries

Comment: Have you installed pyautogui using these steps [Link](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You named your file pyautogui.py, so when it runs `import pyautogui`, it's actually importing your file and not the real PyAutoGUI module. Your file doesn't have a `size()` function, which is why this particular error is showing.

You need to rename your file to something else, and delete the pyautogui.py file you saved.